# How to properly require jquery UI in nodejs

Tags: node.js, jquery-ui

I'm developing a node library that depends on jQuery and jqueryUI. I use browserify to make it accessible to a browser page.
So in my library code, there can be for example such kind of code:

```
var createMenu = function (target, options) {
  $target = $(target);
  $target.menu(options);
}
```

I require jQuery and jQueryUI like this:

```
var $ = jQuery = require("./node_modules/jquery");
require("./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist");
```

but when I call `createMenu` function in the browser, it logs `TypeError: $target.menu is not a function`.

JQueryUI doesn't seem to be properly loaded but I didn't find documentation on how to load it properly.

I also tried `$.ui = require('./node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js')` without any more luck.

If I do the following:

```
jQueryUI = require("./node_modules/jquery-ui")
console.log(jQueryUI)
```

it only logs an empty object.

Any idea on the proper way to log jQueryUI to use it in nodejs?

Comment: Why do you need a frontend library (jQuery UI) in a backend (NodeJS) module?

Comment: @Sirko Nodejs is a convenient context to develop a library. Even if I use this library only in frontend after "browserifying" it. With node I can easily manage dependencies, import modules...

Comment: @chateau JQuery is not a good choice as it depends on the global `window` object which simply does not exist server side where node runs. JQuery is for traversing the DOM and some simple animations. I don't expect this is what you are trying to do server side? Maybe you can give more context of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Strech0 Yes I'm not using jQuery in the server side, I use it in the browser (after "browserifying" the library). But I'm developing many libraries with node and node is convenient for requiring other modules, and it is a good development context for me as I have prebuilt utilities that I use in other libraries. However the functions from the library will be used from the browser, and in the browser, I pass a jQuery object to them that gives the DOM context.

Comment: Have you eventually find a way to include jQuery UI?

Comment: @HéloïseChauvel nope, I didn't find any proper way, I'm still loading it from the browser, that's the only way I'm able to make it work so far.

Answer (score 1):

These steps should work:

Install these packages from npm

```
npm install jquery
npm install jquery-ui-dist
```

Import them in HTML file, like

```
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```